# Symfony and User-to-User Paypal payments

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I hope I can get help from anyone of you.

I'm implementing a platform where users can purchase goods among them, without paying money to my Paypal. Each seller must have a Paypal account. I'm using Symfony2 platform with JMSPaymentPaypalBundle, and I am trying to get inspired by the code at http://symfony2.ylly.fr/how-to-set-up-jmspayment-bundle-and-add-the-paypal-plugin-sebastien/#comment-3117. Unfortunately, I am not really experienced in Paypal interface, API and so forth.

Within that code, it's clear that the express checkout is done on the paypal account registered by the config.yml setting. But it's not my case. I want that UserA purchases something from UserB and pay the order to UserB via Paypal Express Checkout to UserB. Please, can someone give some hints (even some documentation to refer to) on how to adapt the code to my case, by exploiting express checkout too or anything else?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Is this even officially supported by PayPal? I mean: I could send someone money. But triggering an OTHER account to send money to an even third accout is not possible, I think. 

Either you receive money, or send it.

Comment: sure it is, you only need to have the username, password and signature of each account

Comment: I suppose I am using the wrong tool. I read that it's possible with adaptive payments. Is it, please?